# RavenDB and Constructor Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, ravendb, constructor-injection

In my project, I have the following `PageCache` entity, which is being stored in RavenDB:

```
public class PageCache
{
    private readonly IHtmlDocumentHelper htmlDocumentHelper;

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public PageCache(IHtmlDocumentHelper htmlDocumentHelper, string url)
    {
        this.htmlDocumentHelper = htmlDocumentHelper;
        this.Url = url;
    }
}
```

I am using Castle Windsor to inject the `IHtmlDocumentHelper` implementation at runtime. This member is used in methods defined inside the `PageCache` class, which I stripped from the above snippet for the sake of simplicity.

When I create a `PageCache` object using the constructor, everything works fine. But elsewhere in my code, I load `PageCache` objects back from RavenDB:

```
public PageCache GetByUrl(string url)
{
    using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Query<PageCache>()
                      .Where(x => x.Url == url)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

My issue is that the objects I get back from RavenDB don't have the `htmlDocumentHelper` member set, rendering the `PageCache` methods that depend on it unuseable.

In other words: when I load objects back from documents stored in RavenDB, it won't use my constructor to build the objects, thus not initializing the private members through constructor injection.

Am I doing something wrong here? How would you solve such an issue?

---

I ended up using the solution proposed by Ayende below. The circular dependency issue I mentioned in the comments only appeared when I registered the `DocumentStore` in Windsor with `UsingFactoryMethod()`. The issue strangely disappeared when I used Windsor's `DependsOn()` and `OnCreate()` to configure and initialize the `DocumentStore` directly inside the `Register()`.

My container is now being initialized as follows:

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(
    // Register other classes, such as repositories and services.
    // Stripped for the sake of clarity.
    // ...

    // Register the CustomJsonConverter:
    Component.For<CustomJsonConverter>().ImplementedBy<CustomJsonConverter>(),

    // The following approach resulted in an exception related to the circular
    // dependencies issue:
    Component.For<IDocumentStore>().UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
        Application.InitializeDatabase(container.Resolve<CustomJsonConverter>()))

    // Oddly enough, the following approach worked just fine:
    Component.For<IDocumentStore>().ImplementedBy<DocumentStore>()
        .DependsOn(new { Url = @"http://localhost:8080" })
        .OnCreate(new Action<IDocumentStore>(store =>
            store.Conventions.CustomizeJsonSerializer = serializer =>
                serializer.Converters.Add(container.Resolve<CustomJsonConverter>())))
        .OnCreate(new Action<IDocumentStore>(store =>
            store.Initialize()))
        .OnDestroy(new Action<IDocumentStore>(store =>
            store.Dispose()))
    );
```

Although it seems to be working fine, I feel odd having to call `container.Resolve<CustomJsonConverter>()` from inside the `container.Register()` method.

Is this a legal approach to register the dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christian,
We can't use your ctor, we don't know what to put in there.

Instead, you can use this technique to tell RavenDB how to create your objects:
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/CustomCreationConverter.html

Then you can wire this in using documentStore.Conventison.CustomizeSerializer

Comment: Thanks for the support, Ayende. The problem I'm having now is that this CustomSerializer will depend on the HtmlDocumentHelper implementation (so it can pass it onto the PageCache constructor). But HtmlDocumentHelper currently depends on a PageCacheRepository, which itself depends on the DocumentStore for persistance in the database. Since the DocumentStore now depends on this CustomSerializer, we have created circular dependencies which Windsor can't resolve.

Comment: In other words, we now have the following dependencies: HtmlDocumentHelper -> PageCacheRepository -> DocumentStore -> CustomSerializer -> HtmlDocumentHelper.

Comment: @Ayende Does that option require the model to have public setters in the linked reference?

Comment: Couldn't you folks do something like what the MongoDB 2 C# driver does with its BsonConstructor? It maps constructor arguments by name to readonly properties, so that you can have truly immutable objects in the vein of `class Foo { [BsonConstructor]public Foo(Bar MyBar) { this.Bar = bar; } [BsonElement] public Bar MyBar { get; }  }`. This has been the primary thing keeping me with MongoDB in fact.